# Handlebars PHP implementation and nested if/else issues

Tags: php, if-statement, handlebars.js

I'm using the Handlebars **PHP** implementation from https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php

In a Handlebars template I'm using a nested `if/else`, see the template below:

```
 <div class="text-align-{{ options.alignment }} border-bottom-{{ options.style }}" style="border-width: {{ options.width }}px; border-color: {{ options.color }}">
    {{#if options.use_title_separator}}
        <div>
            {{#if options.back_to_top}}
                <a href="" onclick="return false;">{{ options.text_label }}</a>
            {{else}}
                {{ options.text_label }}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

which is working ok in a **PHP 5.4** installation but in a **PHP 5.2** installation it throws the following error:

```
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in <b>/.../Handlebars/Helpers.php</b> on line <b>71</b><br />
```

The conflictive code seems to be:

```
$this->add(
        'if', 
        function ($template, $context, $args, $source) {
            $tmp = $context->get($args);
            $buffer = '';

            if ($tmp) {
                $template->setStopToken('else');
                $buffer = $template->render($context);
                $template->setStopToken(false);
                $template->discard($context);
            } else {
                $template->setStopToken('else');
                $template->discard($context);
                $template->setStopToken(false);
                $buffer = $template->render($context);
            }
            return $buffer;
        }
    );
```

I'm a complete **PHP** noob and I'm just using this Handelbars PHP implementation to have the same templates across several varios environments.

Can you help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The library is not compatible with PHP 5.2, as simple as that. It has nothing to do with nested anythings. It's using anonymous functions and thereby requires at least PHP 5.3.

Comment: Why the close vote? Is a **SO** valid question that can be useful for other users!

Comment: @deceze: I know can be painful, but can you help me to convert the functions to something **5.2** valid? I will try to declare the functions before and pass it instead of the anonymous function in the meantime but as I said, my PHP knowledge is very little to none.

Comment: This is probably not the only place where PHP 5.3 features are used. Backporting it to 5.2 may or may not be a lot of work. I suggest you ask the author for his opinion first via a Github issue.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks, that was exactly was I did but I really didn't expected to be attended faster than SO community :D Now, with his help the issue is solved! I will post an answer for reference. Thanks! You help me a lot with the tip on anonymous functions support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the @deceze and one of the Handlebars PHP project contributors (@everplays) help I could find a solution to this :D

See more details at https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php/issues/16#issuecomment-23017993, hopefully my push request will be accepted and support for **PHP 5.2** at least on the helpers section will be added to the project.

This is the answer from @everplays:

> Just make helpers (
>   https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php/blob/8eb732f407121392015b1bcf032f8e4287fb3969/src/Handlebars/Helpers.php#L67
>   ) `static` and register 'em like: `$this->add('if,
>   array('Handlebars_Helpers', '_if'))`.
>
> For example if helper (defined in `line 71`), should be like:

```
public static function _if($template, $context, $args, $source) {
  // body is the same
}
```

So I repeated that pattern for all current helpers inside the `addDefaultHelpers()` function, like this:

```
/**
 * Create handler for the 'with' helper.
 * Needed for compatibility with PHP 5.2 since it doesn't support anonymous functions.
 *
 * @param $template
 * @param $context
 * @param $args
 * @param $source
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
  public static function _helper_with($template, $context, $args, $source) {
    $tmp = $context->get($args);
    $context->push($tmp);
    $buffer = $template->render($context);
    $context->pop();
    return $buffer;
}

   ...

protected function addDefaultHelpers()
{
    $this->add(
        'if',
        array('Handlebars_Helpers', '_helper_if')
    );

    $this->add(
        'each',
        array('Handlebars_Helpers', '_helper_each')
    );

    $this->add(
        'unless',
        array('Handlebars_Helpers', '_helper_unless')
    );

    $this->add(
        'with',
        array('Handlebars_Helpers', '_helper_with')
    );

    //Just for compatibility with ember
    $this->add(
        'bindAttr',
        array('Handlebars_Helpers', '_helper_bindAttr')
    );
}
```

and come to the following version of the `Helpers` file:

https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php/pull/17/commits

Hopefully, it will be added soon to main branch so its fixed in the main project.

Thanks to all

Comment: In the `public static function _f` function: not is `_f` else `_if`.

Answer (score 0):

The library is designed for PHP 5.3 and up. However, if you want, I rewrote those parts to all work with PHP 5.0 and up, when porting to my platform:

https://github.com/EGreg/Q/tree/master/platform/classes/Handlebars
https://github.com/EGreg/Q/blob/master/platform/classes/Q/Handlebars.php

enjoy!